# 'Tris to Quads' on narrow faces does nothing

Tags: modeling

As the question title states I tried importing a svg file, went to Edit mode A to select ALL, and control F, selected tris to quad and it won't work. 
What am I doing wrong?[image]

here's the blend file

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, .svg imports as curve objects. Have you converted to mesh with Alt  +  C  -> 'Mesh from curve/ meta/ surf/ text'?

Comment: AFAIK tris to quads only converts where its easily possible to do so by dissolving a single edge. For something like this where you a have far higher number of verts on the inside than the outside, quads are just not possible without much more drastic measures.

Answer (score 2):

Try increase the maximum angle threshold, this will give you quads, but they won't be very *square*.

For better results, run: **Mesh -> Faces -> Beautify Faces** first.

Comment: Hi. Yes I had done  Alt + C -> 'Mesh from curve/ meta/ surf, and i just tried Beautify too. No changes whatsoever. But thanks for your suggestions nonetheless.

Comment: Added the blend file to my question in case anyone has time to take a crack at looking at it...

Comment: @Marc, re: *"i just tried Beautify too. No changes whatsoever"* - The blend file does not look like the screenshot. so it seems you ran Beautify at some point. Loading your file and converting tris to quads works here without changing any settings.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. My file looks absolutely no different than the first picture I uploaded. Yes.. I did run Beautify -- but it did nothing that I could tell. I STILL got nothing but triangles all over the place which makes it impossible to bevel the edges.  If you managed to get it to change to quads I'd loooove to know how you did it. I go into edit. select all, mesh/faces/tris to quads ---annnnnnd NOTHING. To be sure I JUST tried it again, for the 10th time. NOTHING. Not that I doubt you but what am I doing wrong then?

Comment: @Marc, double checked - its very different, zoom in and see the distribution of faces on the on the `ar`, in the image these are aligned horizontally, in the blend they aren't. - Take the same screenshot from this blend file and you will see the difference. Also, running **tris to quads** on your blend file works here - so there is some strange disconnect here.

Comment: PART 1 @ ideasman42: I stand corrected. Working with the same file (to be sure I downloaded it from here) I did notice some VERY MINOR improvement when I ran tris to quads. HOWEVER I still have a TON of triangles. Tris to quads, in my mind, should turn everything TO QUADS, leaving NO triangles. Basically, my end result / hope, was to somehow vastly reduce the triangles in the faces to quads or WHATEVER method would allow me to 1) alt select the outline edges all the way around each letter so that 2) I could bevel them.

Comment: PART 2: As it is now when I alt select an edge it only selects a FEW adjoining edges... then I have to keep alt + shift selecting all the way around and it becomes impossible when I get to areas where there's so many tightly packed triangles I can't select an outline edge without getting unwanted edges too. Plus to do it that way, alt+shift selecting, all the way around every letter would take hours of tedious work. I want to bevel the edges of this darn logo. How do I do reduce the amount of faces / edges so I can do that?