# tris_convert_to_quads is not always working

Tags: modeling, python, objects

I have a set of objects which initially come as mix of triangles,quads and ngons as you can also see in the image below:

[image]

I would like to transform them all to quads. The proposed solution that I've found is to use the [bpy.ops.mesh.tris_convert_to_quads](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.tris_convert_to_quads) operator. However, this doesn't seem to always work, below the code snippet I used:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
scene = C.scene

for ob in C.selected_objects:
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        scene.objects.active = ob #set active object
        for vert in ob.data.vertices:
            vert.select = True #ensure all vertices are selected
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') #switch to edit mode
        bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles() #remove doubles
        bpy.ops.mesh.tris_convert_to_quads() #tris to quads
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT') #switch to object mode
```

I've tried to play a bit with the angle thresholds as suggested but it didn't work as well. Any idea how I can transform all triangles to quads?

Here are some of the links with the proposing solution (but all end up with the same problem that it doesn't always work):

['Tris to Quads' on narrow faces does nothing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43814/tris-to-quads-on-narrow-faces-does-nothing)

https://blenderartists.org/t/help-converting-tris-to-quads/518437

https://blenderartists.org/t/remove-doubles-and-tris-to-quads-for-all-imported-meshes-at-once/646911

https://blenderartists.org/t/converting-triangles-to-quads-on-multiple-meshes-objects/548173/7

https://blenderartists.org/t/why-doesnt-convert-triangle-to-quads-work/376707/9

[How can I decimate a mesh to remove unnecessary triangles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/how-can-i-decimate-a-mesh-to-remove-unnecessary-triangles?rq=1)

And here I attach the .blend file:

[image]

---

Update:

Ok, I've tried the [quadremesher](https://exoside.com/quadremesher/) addon which seems to work quite nicely. I have one issue though, I have the following the script running:

```
import bpy
import time

# set quadremesher parameters
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.use_materials = True
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.adaptive_size = 100
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.target_count = 5000
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.adapt_quad_count = True
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.autodetect_hard_edges = True

# create list of objects
obs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
        if o.type == 'MESH']

# loop over objects and apply remesh
for ob in obs:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # Deselect all objects    
    #Set active object to variable
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    if ob: ob.select_set(True)

    print(ob.name)

    # remesh object!!!!!    
    ret = bpy.ops.qremesher.remesh()
    print('Ret: {}'.format(ret))
```

however the operator returns `"{RUNNING MODAL}"` this has an affect that only the last object is remeshed because the operator is called multiple times before the first call is finished. Thus, I would like to have the loop going to the next iteration only after the operator is finished a similar issues is described [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/wait-for-operator-to-finish/1260042/17) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199788/106722). I am not sure though how to exactly apply this wrapper and `callback()` calls in my case with the for loop. Thus, any insight will be helpful.

---

Update 1:

Ok, I've managed to modify my script to work with the wrapper linked above and here is the code snippet:

```
import bpy

from quad_remesher_1_1 import QREMESHER_OT_remesh as op

def remesh_object(obs):
    if obs:
        ob = obs.pop(0)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # Deselect all objects    
        #Set active object to variable
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
        if ob: ob.select_set(True)

        print("Object: {}".format(ob.name))

        # remesh object!!!!!    
        bpy.ops.qremesher.remesh()

# some callback function - here we put what shall be run after the modal is finished
def callback(ret):
    print('Callback triggered: {} !!'.format(ret))

    remesh_object(obs)
    
def modal_wrap(modal_func, callback):

    def wrap(self, context, event):
        ret, = retset = modal_func(self, context, event)
        if ret in {'FINISHED'}: # my plugin emits the FINISHED event on finish - yours might do FINISH or CANCELED, you might have to look it up in the source code, __init__.py , there look at the modal() function for things like return {'FINISHED'} or function calls that return things alike.
            print(f"{self.bl_idname} returned {ret}")
            callback(ret)
        return retset
    return wrap

op._modal_org = op.modal
op.modal = modal_wrap(op.modal, callback)


# set quadremesher parameters
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.use_materials = True
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.adaptive_size = 100
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.target_count = 5000
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.adapt_quad_count = True
bpy.context.scene.qremesher.autodetect_hard_edges = True


obs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
        if o.type == 'MESH']
        
remesh_object(obs)
```

and the output:

[image]

Considering that the plugin is not open source, my provided solution might not be the ideal. Thus, if someone can come up with another solution I would be glad if he can share it.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, and I think I know how to wait for the output. But my problem is I can't even run quad remesher from blender python. Are you sure your code works? When I try to run my code, or your code, I get: `cancel called!!!` and `Error: Python: RuntimeError: expected class QREMESHER_OT_remesh, function cancel to return None, not set`

Comment: @Spectraljump I do not have such an issue. Btw, how did you manage to get the script to wait for the output?

Comment: First I was going to use `asyncio` to just make a coroutine wait and check if the selected object has "Retopo_" in its name yet -- which means QR finished :). But I couldn't run QR from python! I talked to the dev and he said it doesn't work but I can make it work in the scripts. After debugging I got it to work by replacing the `self.timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.3, window=context.window)` in the `def execute(` function in the `class QREMESHER_OT_remesh(bpy.types.Operator):` in `qr_operators.py` with my own recursive timer function version of the `def modal(self, context, event):`

Comment: It was failing for the same reason you can't wait for results: blender `context.window_manager` `wm.event_timer` & `wm.modal_handler` somehow don't work correctly / at all from python.

So I edited the `def modal(self, context, event):` func into `def no_modal(self, context):` -- which doesn't use modals, doesn't use events, is just a recursive func that polls with a `time.sleep(0.3)`. This works because 1. QR runs an internal exe in a separate thread so it doesn't block, and 2. time.sleep does block our py script which means we can wait for the result so no need for my initial asyncio plan.

Comment: Cool, possibly you could add your solution as an answer here. Thus, if anyone else stumbles upon this thread can have both alternatives.